# WordPress | WP_Query('s=a') returns nothing

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code:

```
$data = new WP_Query('s=a');
```

and the print_r returns the following data:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [s] => a
            [error] => 
            [m] => 0
            [p] => 0
            [post_parent] => 
            [subpost] => 
            [subpost_id] => 
            [attachment] => 
            [attachment_id] => 0
            [name] => 
            [static] => 
            [pagename] => 
            [page_id] => 0
            [second] => 
            [minute] => 
            [hour] => 
            [day] => 0
            [monthnum] => 0
            [year] => 0
            [w] => 0
            [category_name] => 
            [tag] => 
            [cat] => 
            [tag_id] => 
            [author_name] => 
            [feed] => 
            [tb] => 
            [paged] => 0
            [comments_popup] => 
            [meta_key] => 
            [meta_value] => 
            [preview] => 
            [sentence] => 
            [fields] => 
            [menu_order] => 
            [category__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [category__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [post__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__not_in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__in] => Array
                (
                )

            [tag_slug__and] => Array
                (
                )

            [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
            [suppress_filters] => 
            [cache_results] => 1
            [update_post_term_cache] => 1
            [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
            [post_type] => any
            [posts_per_page] => 10
            [nopaging] => 
            [comments_per_page] => 50
            [no_found_rows] => 
            [search_terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                )

            [order] => DESC
        )

    [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                )

            [relation] => AND
        )

    [meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                )

            [relation] => 
        )

    [post_count] => 0
    [current_post] => -1
    [in_the_loop] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [current_comment] => -1
    [found_posts] => 0
    [max_num_pages] => 0
    [max_num_comment_pages] => 0
    [is_single] => 
    [is_preview] => 
    [is_page] => 
    [is_archive] => 
    [is_date] => 
    [is_year] => 
    [is_month] => 
    [is_day] => 
    [is_time] => 
    [is_author] => 
    [is_category] => 
    [is_tag] => 
    [is_tax] => 
    [is_search] => 1
    [is_feed] => 
    [is_comment_feed] => 
    [is_trackback] => 
    [is_home] => 
    [is_404] => 
    [is_comments_popup] => 
    [is_paged] => 
    [is_admin] => 
    [is_attachment] => 
    [is_singular] => 
    [is_robots] => 
    [is_posts_page] => 
    [is_post_type_archive] => 
    [query_vars_hash] => 1015947de489d0153582586bded7c016
    [query_vars_changed] => 
    [thumbnails_cached] => 
    [query] => Array
        (
            [s] => a
        )

    [request] => SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=2
    [posts] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

What is wrong with this query and does not return any data ? Also take a look at the "requer" where it is "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=2"

Comment: Like so `add_action( 'init', function() { var_dump( new WP_Query('s=a') ); die(); }, -1 );` in an empty plugin file if possible. That way you'll eliminate any theme or plugin overrides. If it works, you'll have to look for what is overriding the query internally, by switching all plugins off and setting theme to one of the default ones, then enabling them one by one.

Comment: @soulseekah: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly, there is something else wrong in my case, because I have try the excact code and still I am getting the query "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=2"

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugins and switching to twentyten?

Comment: Unfortunatly not. The truth is that I am working on a spageti project, and this is the main issue of handret of issues.

Comment: Inspect all filters here http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php step-by-step. There isn't a query saying `WHERE 1=2`, so `grep` through all `wp-content` for 'WHERE 1=2' to find where it may be coming from. Something seems to be overwriting the search functionality, I bet some "Advanced Search" plugin/theme functionality.

Comment: While you're at it, `grep`ping for https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters any of these will yield some suspects as well.

Comment: The issue generated by the Relevanssi WordPress plugin, that was installed by another developer, before I start maintaining the site. Anyway, thank you so much for your assistance !!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran in to this exact same problem. My case also turned out to be due to the Relevanssi search plugin.

I found [this](http://www.relevanssi.com/knowledge-base/query_posts/#comment-1635153371) in the Relevanssi support forums.

Add this to your theme's `functions.php` or somehere in your plugin.

```
add_filter('relevanssi_prevent_default_request',   'rlv_fix_archive_kill', 10, 2);
function rlv_fix_archive_kill($kill, $query) {
    if (empty($query->query_vars['s'])) $kill = false;
    return $kill;
}
```

Comment: You might also want to fully disable Relevanssi in some scenarios, you can do that in two lines of code as described in here https://www.relevanssi.com/knowledge-base/how-to-disable-relevanssi/